# Evaluate $\int\frac{(-x_{0}+R\cos(\theta))\,d\theta}{\left((-x_{0}+R\cos(\theta))^2+(-R\sin(\theta))^2\right)^{3/2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

As the title suggests, how may I start evaluating the following integral:

\begin{align}I=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\left(-x_{0}+R\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)\,d\theta}{\left((-x_{0}+R\cos(\theta))^2+(-R\sin(\theta))^2\right)^{3/2}},\;\text{for }\color{red}{x_{0}>R}.\end{align}

It appeared while trying to find the resultant electric field in a plane containing a circular ring of charge. My Physics professor suggested that an elliptic integral would pop up, is this that elliptic integral? I don't know which substitution to make to make it look more obvious.

Comment: Are $x_0$ and $R$ postive real numbers, so $x_0,R\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: @JanEerland Yes, that's the assumption I built the integrand on.

Comment: It looks like there will be elliptic functions in the primitive, yes. If you have limits on the integral, you might have a chance (I've not tried any cases) to get an elementary answer...